# puphpet send email ubunutu 12 apache2

Tags: email, vagrant, puphpet

I am trying to send email to my machine from my puphpet virtual machine and I can't seem to have php send email. If I run

```
    vagrant up
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

I can then send email via the vagrant ssh terminal, which works great but I would like to send it to my machine via php's mail function.

```
    mail -s "test" me@email.com
    crtl+d
    ctrl+d
```

I am running this script which does not seem to work.

```
    $ok = mail('me@domain.com', 'test', 'test');
    var_dump($ok);
```

I have tried installing postfix email and also sendmail. Any ideas as to why php will not send any email...

**update**

I added this line to my **config.yaml** file in the puphpet folder. I also changed mailcatcher to 0. I then ran vagrant provision again. It works great now, no delay at all, just make sure sendmail/postfix is installed. sudo apt-get install sendmail or postfix

```
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
```

farther down...

```
 ini: 
       sendmail_path: '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your web server's log file?  Your PHP script is probably looking for the mail command on the wrong place on your system.  Maybe the symbolic link for mail is not on the right place or missing?  You mention you did postfix and sendmail.

On my ubuntu system I have postfix and the mail symbolic link is at /usr/bin/mail.

Try also from command line to run "php -i |grep mail".  On mine I see:

```
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
mailparse
mailparse support => enabled
mailparse.def_charset => us-ascii => us-ascii
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
MAIL => /var/mail/root
_SERVER["MAIL"] => /var/mail/root
```

Check out the "sendmail path" (even on postfix it shows like that) and the "path to sendmail".  Make sure these are set correctly according to what you have on your system.

Comment: It looks like it's is adding mailcatcher to the end in php.ini file. I have tried changing that the send mail path and no luck. I have turned on php short tags so I know the ini is working, it seems like the path is off but I can't seem to update it. I have restarted apache also.